# Rest API Documentation - getChanges query options

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, documentation, getchanges

Where can I find all available query options for getChanges?

```
/_api/site/getchanges(@qry)?@qry={}
```

I know I can query using `{"Add":true,"Web":true}` but I'd like to know all properties I can specify.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation can be found here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj245903(v%3doffice.15)

You can set boolean values for SharePoint objects (Site,Web,List,View,Item,etc) and the type of change you are interested in eg RoleAssignmentAdd.